# Event handling for dynamic controls in VB6

Tags: vb6, event-handling

How can i achieve event handling for dynamic controls in VB6? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to declare a module-level variable of the same type as the control, and use the `WithEvents` keyword. For example

```
Option Explicit
' Declare object variable as CommandButton and handle the events.'
Private WithEvents cmdObject As CommandButton 

Private Sub Form_Load()
   'Add button control and keep a reference in the WithEvents variable'
   Set cmdObject = Form1.Controls.Add("VB.CommandButton", "cmdOne")
   cmdObject.Visible = True
   cmdObject.Caption = "Dynamic CommandButton"
End Sub

'Handle the events of the dynamically-added control'
Private Sub cmdObject_Click()
    Print "This is a dynamically added control"
End Sub
```

There are more complicated variations if you want to be able to handle events from many different controls, perhaps of different types, through one central routine.

Comment: As an aside to all of this; if you want to remove the cmdObject completely (aka a "magically" appearing/disappearing cancel button) you can first call 
"Form1.Controls.Remove cmdObject"
then 
"Set cmdObject = Nothing"
And the object will be cleaned up, and you can reinstantiate it later if you so desire.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on whether the control is intrinsic or not.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277578(VS.60).aspx) article explains it.

Comment: Not exactly. It depends on whether you have added a reference to the control into the project. And, nearly all the time, it's best to add the reference. I've written my answer assuming there is a reference.