# Event handling for dynamic array of controls

Tags: vb6, event-handling

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355697/event-handling-for-dynamic-controls-in-vb6) to handle events for a dynamically created control in VB6 and I tried to use this for my code, but to no avail.

```
Option Explicit  
Private WithEvents grid(0 To 23, 0 To 23) As Frame
```

How can I get the same functionality for this array of controls?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You can either use control arrays where you `Load` new indexes (instances) of your control or write a custom wrapper class that forwards the events through callback methods.

For second option:

- you have a class `cFrameExt` that sinks `Frame`'s events
- on event it calls a callback method on a "parent" object

  - passing `me` as first parameter
- "parent" substitutes `me` with an integer index and raises an event

Most problematic is cyclic references this scheme is usually implemented with.