# Dynamic listview control in excel vba

Tags: listview, dynamic

Would someone kindly share the code required to create a click event handler for a listview control created at run time.  I can create the listview control and populate it but have no idea how to create the class module and associated code in the userform to handle the event.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created and populated the control at runtime, you can just handle the events for the control without creating a class module.

There is a more general question related to dynamically added controls in general that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355697/event-handling-for-dynamic-controls-in-vb6).

But here's an example I wrote specifically for the ListView control. 
Note that you need to declare the control WithEvents to get the events handlers to work. And the "AS" type should be the type you are currently using when creating your ListView.

```
Option Explicit
' Declare object variable as ListView and handle the events.'
Private WithEvents ListView1 As MSComctlLib.ListView 

Private Sub Form_Load()
   'Add button control and keep a reference in the WithEvents variable'
   Set ListView1 = Form1.Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.ListView", "ListView1")
   ListView1.Visible = True
   'Set other properties that need to be set for ListView1 here...'
End Sub

'Handle the events of the dynamically-added control'
Private Sub ListView1_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
    Print "ItemClick Event fired from ListView1"
    Text1.Text = "Selected item: " & ListView1.SelectedItem.Text & ", with index: " & ListView1.SelectedItem.Index
End Sub
```

If you don't have a reference to the actual library of the control in your project, you may try this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents objExt As VBControlExtender ' Declare VBControlExtender variable

Private Sub LoadControl()
   'Here you need to add the license to the control's library, in this case if you have VB6 installed you should be covered
   'Licenses.Add "MSComctlLib.ListView", "xydsfasfjewfe"
   'Here replace with correct library.control name
   Set objExt = Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.ListView", "objExt")
   objExt.Visible = True 
   'Set other properties here...
End Sub

Private Sub objExt_ObjectEvent(Info As EventInfo)
   ' Program the events of the control using Select Case.
   Select Case Info.Name
   Case "Click"
      ' Handle Click event here.
   ' Other cases now shown
   Case Else ' Unknown Event
      ' Handle unknown events here.
   End Select
End Sub
```

See MSD article related to the above [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277578(VS.60).aspx).

Talk to you later.

PS: If you still want to create a wrapper class for the control, see [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?372811-Classic-VB-Why-can-t-I-use-WithEvents-on-arrays-of-objects) an example of a class with an interface that fires an event.