# in vb6, how to capture timer event which the Timer created by code?

Tags: timer, vb6

for program need, I create Timer control by code:

```
Me.Controls.Add "VB.Timer", "timer" & i
```

and I can set its property by this:

```
Me.Controls("timer" & i).Enabled = False
```

usually, we capture timer event by this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
   'some code
End Sub
```

but how can I capture the timer event which the Timer created by code? below code is not working...of course

```
Private Sub Me.Controls("timer" & i)_Timer()
   'some code
End Sub
```

thank you.

Comment: Here is an [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2355697/5162073) showing how it is done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event handling for dynamic controls in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355697/event-handling-for-dynamic-controls-in-vb6)  The timer events are no different than control events.